# Deploying to Google App Engine using 'gcloud app deploy' gets stuck

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

`gcloud app deploy` hangs on deployment with no log messages explaining why. How can I debug this issue?

I have two `.yaml` files and a `dispatch.yaml` file. This is the command I am running:

```
gcloud app deploy web_app.yaml rest_app.yaml dispatch.yaml --verbosity=debug
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This was fixed when I updated gcloud.

`gcloud components update`

This is really bad UX, and I wish gcloud would have asked me to update instead of freezing `app deploy`

Comment: 4 years later they still do this. How difficult it is to show a warning for fail the command?